# How to update cordova plugin on specific platform in project?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to update plugin only for android platform in project. So i decided to do it usng plugman -  uninstall and install again, as it is said in cordova documentation:

```
plugman uninstall --platform android --project platforms\android --plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

But is says - plugin is not installed. I thought, cordova fully copies project for each platform in project, but it seems it s not so - plugins are in main project folder. How does this dependencies work and what should i do to use different version of plugin in specified destination platform ? There are some other changes, so i dont want to recreate android branch.

Tried to follow cordova documentation:

> If you use a platform-centered workflow, you use a lower-level Plugman command-line interface, separately for each targeted platform.

Comment: You can't update for one platform only